# Plotting two Matlab figures next to each other

Tags: matlab, figure, subplot

I'm trying to plot the two figures next to each other. The idea is to create square plots with 1 to 10 on the x-axis. I'm aware of the subplot function but some how it's not working for me. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
   % plotting the data
data1_plot=data1.*100; 
data2_plot=data2.*100; 
figure(1),
subplot(1,2,1); 
plot((1:10)',mean(data1_plot),'o-','LineWidth',1);hold on
for ii=2:10;
    if mean(data1_plot(:,ii))<mean(data1_plot(:,ii-1));
        plot([ii-1,ii],mean(data1_plot(:,ii-1:ii)),'r.-');
    end
end
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'Unprofitable';'2';'3';'4';'5';'6';'7';'8';'9';'Profitable'});
axis([0.8,10.2,0.0,1.5]),...
    ylabel('Average return'),...
    title('\rm Equally-weighted PMU portfolio returns, 1990-2015');hold off;
subplot(1,2,2); 
plot((1:10)',mean(data2_plot),'o-','LineWidth',1);hold on
for ii=2:10;
    if mean(data2_plot(:,ii))<mean(data2_plot(:,ii-1));
        plot([ii-1,ii],mean(data2_plot(:,ii-1:ii)),'r.-');
    end
end
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'Weak';'2';'3';'4';'5';'6';'7';'8';'9';'Robust'});
axis([0.8,10.2,0.0,1.5]),...
    ylabel('Average return'),...
    title('\rm Equally-weighted RMW returns, 1990-2015');hold off;
```

[plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrl2t.png)

Comment: your plot link looks okay (apart from badly formatted) what do you want your plot to look like? Your description is quite vague.

Comment: the plot link is the output. Problem is that when I plot hem as two separate I get two very neat plots with the form of a square. However, when I combine the plots with the subplot function I get the output as given in the link. I hope to combine the two plots without adjusting the sizes

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
axis square
xlim([1 10])
```

The first command makes the current axes region square ([web](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/aspect-ratio-for-2-d-axes.html)) and the second set the x-axis limit.

Example:

```
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(1:10);
axis square
xlim([0 12]);

subplot(1,2,2)
plot(1:10);
axis square
xlim([1 10]);
```

[image]